# How can check in DB table ip address in rage?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have entity

```
public class CrmActionLogIp implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "ip_start")
    private String ipStart;
    @Column(name = "ip_end")
    private String ipEnd;
    @Column(name = "office_name")
    private String officeName;
```

I save ip ti this table. 
if officeName has 1 ip address I save ipStart = ipEnd 
if officeName has range of ips I save ipStart = range start and ipEnd  = range end. For example:

```
id   ipStart       ipEnd          officeName
0    127.0.0.1     127.0.0.1      local office
1    129.127.0.0   129.127.0.12   test office
2    132.127.0.11   132.127.0.22   test office2
```

And How can I get officeName from DB by ip? For exaple I have `129.127.0.5` it is between `129.127.0.0 AND 129.127.0.12` so I get officeName = test office.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will probably take advantage of product specific functionality.)

Comment: @ jarlh Oracle DB

Comment: please take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994142/storing-an-ip-address-in-a-oracle-sql-table when you store ip as hexadecimal value, then you can compare values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this util method

```
public static long ipToLong(String ip) {
        String[] addrArray = ip.split("\\.");

        long ipDecimal = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < addrArray.length; i++) {

            int power = 3 - i;
            ipDecimal += ((Integer.parseInt(addrArray[i]) % 256 * Math.pow(256, power)));
        }
        return ipDecimal;
    }
```

and save 4 columns `ipStart ipEnd ipStartLond ipEndLog`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add two additional columns, i.e. `ipStartNum` and `ipEndNum`, where you convert the ip string value to a number according, for example, using the following formula (this formula is taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27260487/2630032), please upvote if it helps you). Then, when searching for the office based on a particular ip, transform this ip into such a number and do a BETWEEN-query:

```
CREATE TABLE actionlog
    ("id" int, "ipStart" varchar2(12), "ipEnd" varchar2(12), "officeName" varchar2(12), "ipStartNum" number, "ipEndNum" number)
\\

INSERT ALL 
    INTO actionlog ("id", "ipStart", "ipEnd", "officeName")
         VALUES (0, '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1', 'local office')
    INTO actionlog ("id", "ipStart", "ipEnd", "officeName")
         VALUES (1, '129.127.0.0', '129.127.0.12', 'test office')
    INTO actionlog ("id", "ipStart", "ipEnd", "officeName")
         VALUES (2, '132.127.0.11', '132.127.0.22', 'test office2')
SELECT * FROM dual
\\

update actionlog set "ipStartNum" = to_number(regexp_substr("ipStart", '\d+', 1, 1)) * 16777216 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipStart", '\d+', 1, 2)) * 65536 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipStart", '\d+', 1, 3)) * 256 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipStart", '\d+', 1, 4))
\\

update actionlog set "ipEndNum" = to_number(regexp_substr("ipEnd", '\d+', 1, 1)) * 16777216 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipEnd", '\d+', 1, 2)) * 65536 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipEnd", '\d+', 1, 3)) * 256 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipEnd", '\d+', 1, 4))
\\

select * from actionlog
where to_number(regexp_substr('129.127.0.5', '\d+', 1, 1)) * 16777216 +
           to_number(regexp_substr('129.127.0.5', '\d+', 1, 2)) * 65536 +
           to_number(regexp_substr('129.127.0.5', '\d+', 1, 3)) * 256 +
           to_number(regexp_substr('129.127.0.5', '\d+', 1, 4)) between "ipStartNum" and "ipEndNum"
\\
```

Note: to keep values of `ipStartNum` and `ipEndNum` up to date, you could probably use calculated columns, triggers, or java-application based logic as well. See solution based on calculated columns below:

```
CREATE TABLE actionlog
    ("id" int, "ipStart" varchar2(12), "ipEnd" varchar2(12), "officeName" varchar2(12),
     "ipStartNum"  as (to_number(regexp_substr("ipStart", '\d+', 1, 1)) * 16777216 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipStart", '\d+', 1, 2)) * 65536 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipStart", '\d+', 1, 3)) * 256 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipStart", '\d+', 1, 4))),
     "ipEndNum" as (to_number(regexp_substr("ipEnd", '\d+', 1, 1)) * 16777216 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipEnd", '\d+', 1, 2)) * 65536 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipEnd", '\d+', 1, 3)) * 256 +
           to_number(regexp_substr("ipEnd", '\d+', 1, 4))))
```